# Python module setup issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, traceback

So I have the following python script that I call DecisionCat.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import collections
from dataclasses import dataclass

def LoadStructure(filePath):
    tree = ET.parse(rulePath)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for RuleN in root.findall("Rule"):
        NewRule=Rule()
        RNumber=RuleN.attrib['RuleNumber']
        parameters={}
        for child in RuleN:
            if(child.tag == "Rule_Name"):
                RName=child.text
            if(child.tag == "Category"):
                RCat=child.text       
            if(child.tag == "Description"):
                RDesc=child.text
            if(child.tag=="Script_Object"):
                RPath=child.text
            if(child.tag == "Parameter_List"):
               PName=""
               PType=""             
               for Parameters in child:
                   if (Parameters.tag == "Parameter"):
                       for Params in Parameters:
                         if (Params.tag == "Parameter_Name"):
                            PName=Params.text
                         if (Params.tag == "Parameter_Type"):
                            PType=Params.text
                       parameters[PName]=PType                    
        NewRule.RuleName=RName
        NewRule.RuleCat=RCat
        NewRule.RuleDescription=RDesc
        NewRule.RulePath=RPath
        NewRule.Parameterlist=parameters
        catalog[RNumber]=NewRule

class Rule:
    RuleName: str
    RuleCat: str
    RuleDescription: str
    RulePath: str
    Parameterlist:{}
```

I have set up a folder structure consisting of the following.

```py
DecisionCatalog (folder)
          with DecisionCat (folder)
              with __init__.py
                   DecisionCat.py
```

Here is my test script.

```py
import sys
import DecisionCatalog 

RNumber=""
RName=""
RCat=""
RDesc=""
RPath=""
catalog={}
rulePath="../DC_Extension_v6.xml"
LoadStructure(rulePath)
```

I get the following error message.:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "TestCat2.py", line 11, in 
> LoadStructure(rulePath)
> NameError: name 'LoadStructure' is not defined

Can anyone help?

Comment: where is your test script?

Comment: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#:~:text=root%20test%2F%20folder.-,What%20is%20an%20import%20%3F,made%20available%20to%20the%20importer.

Answer (score 1):

In your test script try:

```
from DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat.DecisionCat import LoadStructure
```

Comment: did not work error message:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestCat2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat.DecisionCat import LoadStructure
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat.DecisionCat'

Comment: try `from DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat import LoadStructure` or `from DecisionCat import LoadStructure`

Comment: didn't work different error message though "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestCat2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat import LoadStructure
ImportError: cannot import name 'LoadStructure' from 'DecisionCatalog.DecisionCat' (C:\Users\....\Documents\shop\DecisionCatalog\DecisionCat\__init__.py)"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had DecisionCat.py as DecisionCat..py. I did need to use DecisionCat.LoadStructure.  Problem with working alone can miss the obvious.